# How to display number of matches in incremental search?

Tags: search, emacs

I think ordinary editors can display the number of matches while searching strings like following. How to do this in Emacs? Especially I want to see these numbers while using `isearch-forward` and `isearch-forward-regexp`.

[image]

Comment: This is a part of `occur` functionality. `M-s o`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 3rd party package [anzu.el](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-anzu) displays the current match and the total number of matches of the current incremental search in the mode line.

You can install from [Marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/anzu) or [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/anzu) with `M-x package-install RET anzu`.  Note that neither of these archives are enabled by default in Emacs, so you need to customize `package-archives` as explained in the instructions of the corresponding archive.

Comment: It seems to be what I wanted. This apricot works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @user2931409 You may want to accept the answer then.